# if i am using the setters getters to set the value in one method and i can get get the same value using getters to get it is possible?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, getter-setter

In the below code, there was an error in AccountServices class. There in deposit method i can't get the d.accountNo(); value. it is getting zero only. i can't call the the previous setted value in another method? Could anyone please exlain it to me ??

```
System.out.println("The accno is "+d.getAcc_No()+" and Deposit amount was Rs."+balance);
```

Here's the code .......
https://github.com/moorthysmart/JdbcBank/tree/master/NetLogin

Answer (score 1):

You are basically creating and destroying objects without using it.

You are setting value for object
Dbsetget in Login method, but in Deposit method you are again creating a new Dbsetget object which ofcourse will be empty.

In order to reuse the objects and its values,  you should pass the objects as method arguments or declare them class/instance variables and use the getter method

Comment: how to do it please explain??

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-class-variables-instance-variables-and-local-variables-in-Java